# How to display a custom field in the dashboard posts list( replacing the title )

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm using WordPress and I did create a custom post type with several custom fields ( using ACV, advanced custom fields )
I have hidden all the basic WordPress fields like title, content editor thumbnails, etc, etc so I leave just my custom fields for the creation of a new post.

Since the title is not filled at the creation of the post, I get a list of post with every title set as “auto draft”
The thing that I don't want obviously.

My question is simple :

Is it possible and if yes how to replace the title with one of my custom fields in the dashboard post list.

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find an answer.

Sorry for my English, it’s not my native tongue, I hope You understand what I basically want to do.

Thanks for your time to read my question.
Have a good day

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow brother

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself.

Let us say that you have a custom post type named "test" with 3 custom fields named `one`, `two` and `three`. And you want to remove the title and the date, show the content of `one`, `two`, and `three` in the post list table.

First you have to create a function that removes the title and the date, and also creates the new columns.

```
function custom_columns($columns)
{
    unset($columns['title']);
    unset($columns['date']);
    return array_merge(
        $columns,
        array(
            'one' => __('One'),
            'two' => __('Two'),
            'three' => __('Three')
        )
    );
}
add_filter('manage_test_posts_columns', 'custom_columns');
```

Then you need to display the custom field content in the post list table:

```
function display_custom_columns($column, $post_id)
{
    switch ($column) {
        case 'one':
            echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'one', true);
            break;
        case 'two':
            echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'two', true);
            break;
        case 'three':
            echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'three', true);
            break;
    }
}
add_action('manage_test_posts_custom_column', 'display_custom_columns', 10, 2);
```

[Further reading](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_post_data` to accomplish the desired functionality. This action is triggered when a post is created or updated.

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_updated_title', 99, 1 );

function my_updated_title( $data ) {

  // If this is just a revision, don't update title.
  if ( wp_is_post_revision( $data['ID'] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Set the post title to your custom field value
  $data['post_title'] = get_field( 'your_acf_field', $data['ID'] );

  // Return the updated post data
  return $data;

}
```

Comment: Dude, thanks for your time but you missed my point.
What I want to change is the post listing in the BACK OFFICE. Not in the front.
The title is set as "auto draft" cause i removed the title field in the post editor ( when you create a new post ) and it is okay, I don't want title or any other basic worpress field.
But if I do this, I get a listing with only "autodraft" and a creation date in the back office.
So it will be impossible to identify any post untill you click on them to edit them.

Comment: My apologies, let me revise the answer above.

Comment: No problem man, I probably explained it the wrong way in the first place.

Where should I put this code ?

Comment: Typically this would go in the `functions.php` file.

Comment: I wasn't able to test it when I wrote it. If it doesn't work we might just need to use a different hook.

Comment: Not working at all. I did find a solution. See below if you're interested. 
Thank you very much your time anyway !